# Visual Studio 2015: Windows 8.1 missing ucrtbased.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise With Update 2 on Windows 8.1. While trying to run a project built on Visual Studio 2015, I am facing missing ucrtbased.dll error.  I came across few articles which read that this dll is present on Windows 10 and is a part of OS. I have a Windows 10 OS. But, i am unable to locate the dll.  Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: which win10 build? 10240? If yes, update to 10586 (Version 1511)

Comment: I am using 10586.218 (Version: 1511).

Comment: and where do you get the message? on Win1 or 8.1? For 8.1 install the Universal C Runtime in Windows https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226

Comment: I am getting this error on Win10 also.

Comment: the d means the debug version is missing. Compile it as release not debug.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Win10 SDK (even on Win8.1 with its own SDK installed) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. :)
Repair Visual Studio 2010 and install Universal C++ library.
Might be of help to others. :)